# Change the value of multiple variables in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a given list, with 49 variables each with a value between 1-5. I want to change the value of all variable which is equal to 5 to zero.
Here is what I’ve tried:

```
 For element in listb:
        If element == 5:
            element = 0
```

But it doesn’t have any affect, what is the problem?
Thanks 
Vendel

Comment: (`For` should be `for` , `If` should be `if` all lowercase)

Comment: you're changing the value of another variable/name. rebuild `listb = [x if x != 5 else 0 for x in listb]`

Comment: These questions were not even closely the same but ok, and thanks

Comment: @VendelUtto those are the same questions. Don't believe you're unique. The question has been asked a lot of times here.

Comment: @VendelUtto They'll give you the needed information for you to work it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
listb = [n if n!=5 else 0 for n in listb]
```

Which is a more efficient alternative to

```
 for index in range(listb):
    if listb[index] == 5:
        listb[index]  = 0
```

Infact in `for element in listb:` element is a copied primitive.

This would be different if we had:

```
listb = [[1],[5],[3]]
for element in listb: #element is a copied reference, but to the same element in listb
    if element[0] == 5:
        element[0] = 0
```

Comment: What's a "copied element"? ``element`` will be a reference to the actual item, so if it's mutable and you change it in place, it will also change within ``listb``.

Comment: @MikeScotty copied from python shell: `>>> listb = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [n if n!=5 else 0 for n in listb]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
>>> for element in listb:
...     element = 5
...
>>> listb
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>`

Comment: That's why I wrote ``if it's mutable``. Example: ``listb = [ [] ]
for item in listb:
    item.append(1)
print(listb) `` Result: ``[[1]]``

Comment: Exactly. In that case python will internally copy a reference to the same list (the inner []) and that is mutable. But being a primitive, element, in the main example, is just copied. We probably mean the same thing